# C# permission to read from file

Tags: c#, security, permissions

I'm trying to seralize a json string from a file.

```
using (var re = System.IO.File.OpenText(filePath))
using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(re))
{
     entries = serializer.Deserialize<List<MessageObject>>(reader);
}
```

On the seralizaer row i get the following error:

```
System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 Failed
```

I tried setting the security policy, but still same error.

```
<securityPolicy>
  <trustLevel name="full" policyFile="internal"/>
</securityPolicy>
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: what is the value of `filePath` ?

Comment: private readonly string filePath = @"C:\Projects\Er.txt";

Comment: Try setting the windows file permissions to 'Everyone'. If the problem goes away you can go back and figure out what account the app is running under and grant it the same access.

Comment: I know this may sound stupid but have you tried to start Visual studio with administrator rights ? Sometimes it hangs up on this. Afterwards change the file permission to everyone